# show next page only when all images are loaded in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

would there be any easy way or setting that i can turn on to allow this with jquery mobile?

i just use the normal anchor links to navigate from page to page and let jquery mobile default behavior applies, but the problem is when the next pages shows up, the page flickers.

I want to avoid this - and besides i also want to show the next page only when the entire pages including its images are loaded already. Makes for a better experience for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // do stuff when the entire doc and all assets have been loaed
});
```

or: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/api/events.html

```
$( 'div' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event, ui){
    alert( 'This page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
});
```

UPDATE

```
$( '#pageNameHere' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event, ui){
    $(window).load(function() {
        // do stuff when the entire doc and all assets have been loaed
    });
});
```

Comment: both doesn't work - for some reason i $(window).load would only get triggered on the first time the page loads in the browser. when the next page shows up, even if you had $(window).load in that page, it doesn't get triggered. pageshow - doesn't wait for the images to load.